# Returning a shared library symbol table

Tags: c, dll, plugins, shared-libraries, dlopen

For instance:

```
void* sdl_library = dlopen("libSDL.so", RTLD_LAZY);
void* initializer = dlsym(sdl_library,"SDL_Init");
```

Assuming no errors, initializer will point to the function SD_Init in the shared library libSDK.so.

However this requires knowing the symbol "SDL_Init" exists.

Is it possibly to query a library for all its symbols? Eg, in this case it would return SDL_Init, the function pointer, and any other symbols exported by libSDL.so.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no libc function to do that. However, you can write one yourself (though the code is somewhat involved).

On Linux, `dlopen()` in fact returns the address of a `link_map` structure, which has a member named `l_addr` that points to the base address of the loaded shared object (assuming your system doesn't randomize shared library placement, and that your library has not been  prelinked).

On Linux, a sure way to find the base address (the address of `Elf*_Ehdr`) is to use `dl_iterate_phdr()` after `dlopen()`ing the library.

Having the ELF header, you should be able to iterate over a list of exported symbols (the dynamic symbol table), by first locating the `Elf*_Phdr` of type `PT_DYNAMIC`, and then locating `DT_SYMTAB`, `DT_STRTAB` entries, and iterating over all symbols in the dynamic symbol table. Use `/usr/include/elf.h` to guide you.

Additionally, you could use [libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html), but I'm unable to guide you since I don't have previous experience with it.

Finally note that the exercise is somewhat futile: you'll get a list of defined functions, but you'll have no idea how to call them (what parameters they expect), so what's the point?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a published API for this.  You can either use the nm tool from binutils or examine its source code:
http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/binutils/?cvsroot=src

http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/binutils/nm.c?rev=1.63&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=src

(obviously assuming elf)

Answer (score 1):

The [Boost.DLL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html) offers this functionality through the [`library_info::symbols`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/dll/library_info.html#idm45834100864640-bb) function. Adapted from the tutorial on [Querying libraries for symbols](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html#boost_dll.tutorial.querying_libraries_for_symbols):

```cpp
// Class `library_info` can extract information from a library
boost::dll::library_info inf(libpath);

// Getting exported symbols
std::vector<std::string> exports = inf.symbols();

// Printing symbols
for (std::size_t j = 0; j < exports.size(); ++j) {
    std::cout << exports[j] << std::endl;
}
```

Note that this only works for the symbols that `nm` lists *without* the `--dynamic` flag, i.e., those in the `.symtab` section. It seems like some libraries do not export any symbols in that section. I have opened a [feature request](https://github.com/boostorg/dll/issues/41) to support falling back to the `.dynsym` section in that case.

Answer (score -3):

```
void *dlsym(void *restrict handle, const char *restrict name);
```

> *Return Value*
>
> If *handle* does not refer to a valid
>   object opened by *dlopen()*, or if the
>   named symbol cannot be found within
>   any of the objects associated with
>   *handle*, *dlsym()* shall return NULL.
>   More detailed diagnostic information
>   shall be available through *dlerror()*.

( Source: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html )

In other words, if the symbol isn't found, `dlsym()` will return `NULL`.  Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but that is the simplest way I can find.

Comment: It sounds to me like the OP is looking to get a list of exported symbols from the library.  Which I don't think is possible without doing some parsing of sections in the ELF structure.

Answer (score -3):

The linux **nm** command could be used: http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=nm

Comment: The question appears to be looking for a programatic means of querying the symbol table of a shared library.  `nm` is a command line utility whose text output format varies by platform.