# Is it possible to mangle typename at runtime?

Tags: c++, name-mangling, c++filt

By using `c++filt -t` command, I could demangle the name into proper type name (for instance, `St3foo` -> `std::foo`)

Is there a way to reverse this thing so I could get `St3foo` by typing `std::foo`?

The only thing I could think is by using `typeid(<expr>).name()` but I have to type any typenames during runtime so I could get the following mangled names.

(Note: I'm using GCC compiler on Windows)

Comment: What compiler are you using? I believe g++ has a built-in API for this

Comment: im using gcc (g++)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11335624/21567?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Linux utility to mangle a C++ symbol name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335624/what-is-linux-utility-to-mangle-a-c-symbol-name)

Comment: In general, no. In order to mangle C++ names you need to parse a valid C++ program that contains them.

Comment: It's impossible. As a fairly obvious example, the mangling of `void foo(bar)` depends on whether "bar" is a type alias or not.