# How does the dlsym work?

Tags: glibc, dlopen, dlsym

it's very easy to find how to **use** dlsym() and other functions from this family, but how does it **work** internally? Is it possible to write own, easy implementation of dlsym()?

I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve similar behavior but **without** linking with -ldl (lets say I can't do this).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> how does it work internally?

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2694373/50617) explains, in GLIBC the first parameter is actually a pointer to `struct link_map`, which contains enough info to locate the dynamic symbol table of the shared library. Once the symbol table and `DT_HASH` or `DT_GNU_HASH` are located, `dlsym` uses one or the other hash table to find the given symbol name.

> Is it possible to write own, easy implementation of dlsym()?

Yes. If you don't care about the speed of lookup, you can simply do linear search of the dynamic symbol table. The code to do so is quite simple, especially if the shared library has (optional) section header: all you need to do is find location of `.dynsym` and `.dynstr` sections in memory, and then (assuming you are looking for symbol `"foo"`)

```
const char *strtab = ... /* locate .dynstr */
const ElfW(Sym) *sym = ... /* locate .dynsym */

for (; sym < end_of_dynsym; ++sym) {
  if (strcmp(strtab + sym->st_name, "foo") == 0) {
    /* found it */
    return load_address + sym->st_value;
  }
}
/* symbol not found */
return NULL;
```

If you do care about lookup speed (`dlsym` certainly does), you'll need to decode `.hash` or `.gnu_hash`, which is a bit more complicated. You could start [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160423182840/https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/gnu_hash_elf_sections).